# Vectors for a 2D/3D World in Java

Tags: java

I reading about Mathematics in Games and am wondering what is the best way to represent a Vector location in Java.

I know there is a Vector class but I don't think this is what I need.

There is also a Matrix class which looks like it may be what I want (a 1 dimensional matrix maybe).

In particular, if I were to create a location Vector such as:

v(x,y,z) where x,y and z are the coordinates in 3D space, what would be the best way to represent this in Java.  It would be nice if I could also add, subtract and find the dot-product of Vectors.

ideas?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could create a 3DVector class

example:

```
class 3DVector {
   int x , y, z;

    public 3DVector(int x, int y, int z){
       //constructor
    }


    public 3DVector add(3DVector anotherVector){

    }

    public 3DVector subtract()....

    public 3DVector doProduct().....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for this,  See :
javax.vecmath.Vector3d

Answer (score 0):

There is a math library out there but a simple class with 3 floating point numbers is what everyone else uses

Comment: It just seems that this would be such a common task that the Java library would offer a default optimized class.

Comment: probably not as common as you think :-)